# How to insert a Hyperlinks VBScript

Tags: html, hyperlink, vbscript

This is my signature script.
I need to put a Hyperlink in the LinkedIn image.

How can i do it?

```
htmlfile.WriteLine("  <p class=MsoNormal><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id=""Picture_x0020_2"" o:spid=""_x0000_i1026""")
htmlfile.WriteLine("   type=""#_x0000_t75"" style='width:13.5pt;height:13.5pt;visibility:visible;")
htmlfile.WriteLine("   mso-wrap-style:square'>")
htmlfile.WriteLine("   <v:imagedata  src=""BBCR_arquivos/image002.jpg"" o:title=""""/>")
htmlfile.WriteLine("  </v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=18 height=18")
htmlfile.WriteLine("  src=""BBCR_arquivos/image003.jpg"" v:shapes=""Picture_x0020_2""><![endif]><span")
```

Comment: What hyperlink do you want to put where?

Comment: Sorry Marc B. Comment deleted.

Comment: Make it more readable and adding a missing tag for better search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use html escaped format. you can use following link

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html